# c++ void with just parameter type

Tags: c++, void

I was reading some tutorials and making a code but met a simple weird function method that a void function with **just parameter type** not actual parameter like: "void foo(int)".

I know that if I make a code like "**void foo(void)**" that means it definitely doesn't allow me to pass parameters but have no idea what means if parameter has **just type 'int.'** It wasn't even a function declaration, but a function **definition**.

First, I thought it may mean I can pass any int variable but it wasn't. If anyone knows this, could you please teach me what this is about? Thank you for reading and your time. The code is below:

```
struct SA{
void display()  { cout << "struct sA without int" << endl; }
void display(int) { cout << "Struct sA" << endl; } // this is it. I have no idea what means putting just type int. I can't even use this function
};

int main(){
    SA sa;
    sa.display(); // I had no problem to call display() but have no idea how to use diplay(int)
}
```

Comment: `void display(int param)` perhaps??

Comment: Thank you for your comment πάντα ῥεῖ! Somehow it was just type not variable, but now I think it is definitely good to avoid this way and use parameter as you mentioned. Thank you for your quick reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply pass an integer to it. It doesn't use it, but that doesn't matter in this context.

```
sa.display(0);
```

Such an approach may be useful in the real situation if you intend to have this function overloaded in the child classes, where this integer will actually be used.

Comment: Thank you very much Volodya! I tried putting an int variable but didn't know I could just pass an integer value. Thank you! I could learn something new! I'll choose this as an answer after mins I'm able to do!

Answer (score 3):

The name of the parameter is optional really. The declaration `void display(int)` is perfectly normal if the parameter will not be used in the function body.

In order to call this method just pass any `int` as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you Archie! So, it is perfcetly normal if it is not used in the function body! I'll also promote your answer! Thank you!!

Comment: Also note that if you did define a name for this input parameter, like `void display(int param)`, then some code-checking tools will complain that you defined a variable `param` but then never used it.

Comment: Oh, I see! Thank you for your further advice! I didn't know this kind of useful technique! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

A `name` is only needed **if you use it**. Since the `parameter` is not used in the `method`, not providing name will not cause any problem.

Comment: Hello again Rakibul! Thank you for your quick answer! So, I see I can just put it like that and it doesn't matter unless I wanna use it. Thank you!